# Running Codes from a text file in Resource Which is Reverse text - vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I took out part of my code, and I've reversed this text. Then I saved the file in the Resource as txt.

I want to read the text from the text file and reverse the text again, and then execute the text as codes.

I used this code to reverse the text:

```
Codes 

Dim TestString As String = My.Resources.rever1

Dim revString As String = StrReverse(TestString)

Dim malk1221 As Assembly = Assembly.Load(revString)

Codes
```

But the program crashed and nothing happened.

Note that there are codes before and after codes.

How do I fix this?

Comment: thats not how it works.  An assembly is *compiled* code, not just text.

Comment: If you convert a binary executable to string, it will change the data. You'll need to first convert it to base64 (hex bytes). Then you can safely manipulate it as a string.

Comment: thank you for the rebly 
I knew that after I did this error
But I want to explain what happened
And what is the right way to do it

Comment: Okuma.Scott .No I dont convert a binary executable to String
I've reversed codes in Visual Basic.net, and he placed them in a text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Assembly.Load` expects an assembly name as argument, not VB source code!

See [How to programmatically compile code by using the Visual Basic .NET or Visual Basic 2005 compiler](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/304654?wa=wsignin1.0) on MSDN.

Here is another example: [Compile and execute code at RunTime](http://www.aboutmydot.net/desktop-applications/compile-and-execute-code-at-runtime.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was useful somewhat
But it is not the answer I'm looking for
Which I meant to ask
That Can I write function in a .txt file
And add this file to the Resource
And then call this function?
I hope that I have explained well
Excuse my language

Comment: In order to call this function, you must compile it first and then run it at runtime. This is what the two links are all about.